# Leaflet popup with angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, leaflet

I've a map that's created with leafletjs. The map has some markers that are like this ev124, ev125 etc.

And there are links that has an attribute called key like `<a ng-click="popup(evsi)" key="124">link</a>`

I'm using angular for this so i can get my key value by using

```
$scope.popup= function(evsi){
   var key = evsi.key;
}
```

Now I have to trigger the click event which is a bultin method for leaflet called openpopup();

```
$scope.popup= function(evsi){
       var key = evsi.key;
       var maker = "ev" + key;
       maker.openpopup();
    }
```

However this is not working and gives me an error, Object eve124 has no method 'openpopup'

How can I fix this? I'm new to angular. Thanks

Comment: maker is a string (`var maker="ev" + key`) so there is no way maker.openpopup() will do anything.  Typically in this case you'd need to create a directive to handle the popup however you aren't sharing enough code (a plunker/fiddle would help).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the events raised when a marker is clicked on?  See http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/events

Also, you might want to check this post out [How to use Angular directives ng-click and ng-class inside Leaflet marker popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662551/how-to-use-angular-directives-ng-click-and-ng-class-inside-leaflet-marker-popup) if you want to do something more clever.