# Leaflet.js add button to marker popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

I am desperately trying to dynamically add buttons into leaflet.js marker popups and assign a callback. However, I seem not to be able to wrap my head around it.

I am using this example https://github.com/calendee/ionic-leafletjs-map-demo and add the following line into line 105 in `js/controller/mapController.js`

```
<button class="icon-left ion-information" ng-click="stationInfoButtonClick('+location.name+')"></button>
```

However, clicking / taping the button does not invoke the specified callback function. Ideas somebody?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add HTML to AngularJS Code. This is not possible just like that.
You need to use $compileProvider for that.

On a previous version of leaflet, I managed to do that by calling the $compileProvider on popUp open.

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.popupopen', function(event, args) {


    var feature = args.leafletEvent.popup.options.feature;

     var newScope = scope.$new();
     newScope.stream = feature;

     $compile(args.leafletEvent.popup._contentNode)(newScope);


});
```

Never done it on ionic indeed, but I'm interested on your return.

Comment: Thanks, the $compileProvider is new to me, but I believe it will be similar to  your solution as Ionic is based on AngularJS.

Comment: Can you share your feedback afterwards ? I'm interested in your return ;)

Comment: I just found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662551/how-to-use-angular-directives-ng-click-and-ng-class-inside-leaflet-marker-popup?rq=1

Comment: and adding getMessageScope: function() { return $scope; },  to the marker specification works! :)

Comment: message: html, getMessageScope: function() { return $scope; } These two lines did the trick ?

Comment: yap, they did the trick... you would have to create the call back function in the current scope though. this way it messes up your code. me no like, but works.