# LEAFLET maps and markers with select options - ANGULARjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I have an app with leaflet maps for showing all my items on maps (I set up markers with pop with info). Now, when the client came to  the page, he need to search map and select markers. In pop up, I will put  the check box. Now, my problem is, when I put another div, where I need to list the selected items. I need to select markers and show it only. Best explanation for this is this [map](https://foursquare.com/explore?mode=url&near=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2C%20United%20States&nearGeoId=72057594043319895&q=comedy).

Comment: Can you please show your code? It's hard to guess what's wrong

Comment: Hi, here is link to plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/SZafhYgLzWyFamdkrWJ0. i don't know how to add maps to plunkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935131/1781026) you can specify a marker that has a popup with an Angular template which works in the same `$scope` as your application, using `getMessageScope`. You can then use all the `ng-` attributes on your HTML elements. I added an `added` attribute to each marker that indicates whether the user has chosen that one (clicked the checkbox) or not, using `ng-model`.

```
amarker:{
  lat: 53.5510,
  lng: 9.9936,
  zoom: 8,
  message: '{{ markers.amarker.options.name }}<br/> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="markers.amarker.added"/>Add',
  getMessageScope: function() { return $scope; },
  options:{
    name: "Marker A"
  },
  added: false
}
```

It's a bit "hacky" because there's no reference back to the marker in the `message`, that's why you have to use `markers.<marker id>` here.

Then when you list all markers it's simply a matter of filtering the `added` attribute:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(markerid,marker) in markers" ng-if="marker.added">{{marker.options.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Demo here: https://plnkr.co/edit/I4CB3tSiViKTiKt1xCXD

Comment: Thanke you very much.  This is what i need.  ☺